# How to avoid angular to rebuild all the modules when running ng test?

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli

I am using a Jenkins pipeline to build my angular 4 application. I am using angular-cli `ng build -prod` and `ng test` to run the tests. The tests' step is extremely slow, taking more time then the build itself. I found out that this was happening because during this step all the modules are rebuilt despite the build had just finished. Isn't there a way to avoid the rebuild during the tests' phase since the modules were already built?

Comment: The modules might be built, but the spec files aren't. You have to let Jasmine do its job. If you want to reduce the execution time of your tests, I suggest you stop relying on the framework (a.k.a. `stop using the Testbed`), which will drastically improve your testing time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? For what I can understand TestBed is what creates the components and injects the dependencies to be tested. What are the alternatives? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little helper I wrote, the [`precompileForTests()`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-ng-dev-utils/typedoc/index.html#precompilefortests) function in [`s-ng-dev-utils`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-ng-dev-utils). It will compile everything for your tests at the beginning of the suite, and cause Angular to re-use the results for each test. I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Following my comment, here is an example of how to test an Angular component without Angular.

Let's say you have a very simple, routed component like so :

```
export class MyRoutedComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigateTo(route: string) {
    this.router.navigate(route);
  }
}
```

The usual test would be to provide the dependency with a mock, and use the Testbed for that.

Well, you aren't forced to, and even [the testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics) tells you so :

> The Angular TestBed facilitates this kind of testing as you'll see in the sections below. But in many cases, testing the component class alone, without DOM involvement, can validate much of the component's behavior in an easier, more obvious way.

What you can do is this :

```
describe('MyRoutedComponent', () => {
  const routerMock = {
    navigate: () => null
  };

  const instance = new MyRoutedComponent(routerMock);

  it('should call router.navigate when navigateTo()', () => {
    spyOn(routerMock, 'navigate');
    instance.navigateTo('foo');
    expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
  });
});
```

As you can see, it tests the component like the Testbed would do, but since it doesn't rely on any HTML, it is a better solution to do that instead, as suggested by the guide.

Comment: But will this avoid the rebuild of the modules? Because that's what is taking 95% of the testing time not the tests themselves. I will try to rewrite the tests without the TestBed where's possible nonetheless and see if there is any improvement in the time.

Comment: Well the answer is pretty simple : do you see any module in my code ? The only possible one would be the routing module, but as you can see, I simply mocked it. And yes, this will greatly reduce the execution time of your tests.

Comment: The problem, like I suspected, is that even if my only spec file contains this `describe('AdminComponent', () => {})` when I run `ng test` it still builds 341 modules taking almost 20 seconds... I assume that these are angular internal modules but that's the main cause of the problem. If only it could use the modules that were previously built in the actual build, that would be great. I have done a great deal of research but no luck.

Comment: Try runnin them from `karma start` in place of `ng test`. `ng` is the command for the Angular CLI, if you use it, you can indeed expect Angular to do something before running your tests.

Comment: With the `karma start` it builds the same 341 modules, so they are karma stuff and not angular's after all... probably nothing we can do about those.

Comment: Are you testing that on your whole project, or in a sandbox ?

Comment: In the whole project.

Comment: And did you change all of your components to remove the Angular context ?

Comment: Yes, I removed all the spec files but one.

Comment: Well I understand that your Typescript has to be compiled, but for instance on my project, I have something around 900 modules being compiled, and it takes less than 5 seconds to run my tests ... Are you complaining about milliseconds, or is it really a seconds/minutes issue ? (honest question, I'm just trying to understand)

Comment: I am complaining about seconds... I am able to run 22 tests in a very simple app in 24 seconds, 20 of which are just for building modules and 4 for the tests themselves, in my local machine. But in the my Jenkins pipeline, it goes as far as 100 seconds for this to happen taking more then 60% of the full build time...

Comment: That's indeed strange. Could you make a simple new project with `ng new XXX` and see if it takes that much time to test ? If yes, then it's an issue with your computer (not powerful enough for instance), if no, then it's an issue with your project.

Comment: With a fresh project from the cli it takes around 12 seconds to run locally. It builds 167 modules instead of 341, but still, the part that takes the most time is the building and the starting of the headless chrome.

Comment: And how much time took your project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174396/discussion-between-antonio-quadrado-and-trichetriche).